# S3 and IAM settings update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

We are in a strange stage at the moment. Our DevOps guy left the organization. Now when we disable his keys in IAM. We saw this kinda error in production. "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied when trying to upload an object on your bucket: XXXXX-prd-asset-images/." If i check Devops Guy IAM , i can see last used as S3 service.  Guys i can understand its a half information but any help would be appreciated.

1. Can we look at prod instances if AWS keys stored there?
2. Can we check any policy?
3. Can we check bucket information?

Answer (score 0):

That Devops guy had his AWS Keys being used for AWS CLI.

You need to create a generic account in AWS IAM which is not used by any developer and system administrator to avoid this situation in future.

Now do one thing create a generic account which has same IAM policies as that of your Devops guy account. SSH to the server. Go to this file `~/.aws/config` there you will find AWS Key and AWS Secret replace that with the new key and secret of the account generated above.

Or you can run following and paste the Key and Access key when prompted and also the proper region for your EC2 instance.

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

Comment: Admin team still working on it. Will update once they are done.